# Library database design foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm designing a library application for my school. We have a 2-3 main libraries and some departments have their own libraries. I wanted to know whether these queries seem correct ?

```
Libraries 
ID Name
1  Walter
2  Wally
3  Maths dept library

Books
ID Book ID  BookName
1   1       Fundamentals of calculus
2   1       Mechanics 
3   2       Fundamentals of calculus
4   2       Biology

Lib_Book_LookUp
ID  libId bookId
1    1     1
2    1     2
3    2     1
4    2     2
```

The two questions I want to solve are:

1. Find how many copies of a particular book exist
2. Find out which libraries have a particular book

Here's what I have:

```
Select count(Book.bookId) where book.name = "Fundamentals of calculus";

Select count(libId) from Lib_Book_lookUp, Book where Book.BookId = Lib_Book_lookUp.bookId groupBy(libId)
```

My questions regarding these queries:

1. Does it seem unnecessary to have a separate lookup table and merge the libId into Books table and have it as a foreign key on the book table ?
2. Do the queries seem correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query is missing a `FROM` clause.  You could also do `COUNT(*)`, but it doesn't particularly matter in this case:

```
 SELECT count(Book.bookId) FROM Books WHERE BookName = "Fundamentals of calculus";
```

To find out which libraries have a particular book, you don't need a `COUNT()` aggregate. Instead you need a `WHERE` clause with your join.  The `COUNT()` would tell you *how many* libraries have a book, but not *which libraries*. For that you want a query which returns `Libraries.Name`.

```
SELECT
  /* Return library names */
  Libraries.Name
FROM 
  Libraries 
  /* Join through your lookup table to match a book name to a library name */
  JOIN Lib_Book_LookUp ON Libraries.ID = Lib_Book_LookUp.libId
  JOIN Books ON Books.ID = Lib_Book_LookUp.bookId
/* Which book to search for */
WHERE Books.BookName = 'Fundamentals of calculus'
```

The lookup table is appropriate because it allows you to normalize books down to a single record in the `Books` table if it exists in multiple libraries.  As you have it, there is no real reason to have multiple copies in the `Books` table, and no reason for the `Book ID` column. In fact, the `Book ID` column as it is is quite misleading.  There are books with two different titles having the same id `1`.

The `Books` table really ought to look like the following, with one record per book title (assuming title as the authority, forgetting about real authoritative things like ISBN)

```
Books
ID BookName
1  Fundamentals of calculus
2  Mechanics 
3  Biology
```

If you have multiple copies of each book possible at each library, you may consider normalizing the books per copy into a table that identifies them by library barcode.  You would then match those ids to libraries as holdings:

```
Books (defines bibliographic details)
ID BookName
1  Fundamentals of calculus
2  Mechanics 
3  Biology

Book_Copies (Matches Books.ID to barcode, barcode is Primary Key)
BookId Barcode
1      1234567
1      1234568
2      8654321
2      8654322

Lib_Book_LookUp (matches book copies to libraries, allowing multiple copies by barcode)
ID  libId bookBarcode
1    1     1234567
2    1     1234568
3    2     8654321
4    2     8654322
```

To query, for example, the number of copies per book per library, you would use:

```
SELECT 
  Libraries.Name,
  Books.BookName,
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  Libraries
  JOIN Lib_Book_LookUp ON Libraries.ID = Lib_Book_LookUp.libId
  JOIN Book_Copies ON Lib_Book_Lookup.bookBarcode = Book_Copies.Barcode
  JOIN Books ON Book_Copies.BookId = Books.ID
GROUP BY 
  Libraries.Name, 
  Books.BookName
```

Comment: Michael, how would you suggest handling the multiple copies of a particular book ? A library can have more than one of "Fundamentals of calculus", for e.g. libraryID = 1 has 3 of them, so adding 3  records in the book db seem like a good idea ?

Comment: @Phoenix In your lookup `Lib_Book_LookUp`, you might add another column for quantity.  However, since library books typically have a unique identifier like a barcode, so you might actually need your `Lib_Book_LookUp` to match the unique barcode with a libraryID.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking I will make the libraryId and bookId as the primary key for the lookUp table. So, if there is a barcode which is 1234567 and there are 2 copies of the same book it will look like this:  1(libId),1234567(bookId),2(copies)

Comment: @Phoenix In my example above, 1234567 and 1234568 are 2 different copies of the same book. It's the barcode that uniquely identifies them by copy, even though they share bibliographic details with `Books.BookId`

Comment: Have a look at the last table in my edited example above.  libId=1 has both the 1234567 and 1234568 copies as separate rows.

Comment: so how can you recognise that they are the same book ? I'll need to join it with books table isbn number correct ?

Comment: @Phoenix `Books.ID --> Book_Copies.BookId`  I'll add a query example above to query number of copies per library per book...

Comment: What will be the best way to determine bookid ? ISBN is publisher specific correct, 2 different publishers in 2 different geographical regions can use the same isbn to refer to 2 different books. So, will the determination of same book be based on, book title, author and edition ?

Comment: @Phoenix That I can't answer... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your database design, you do not need to have a surrogate key on your lookup table. You can simply do a compound primary key of the library and book like so:

```
Lib_Book_LookUp
libId bookId
1     1
1     2
2     1
2     2
```

I made the following changes with your book ID's (mechanics & biology had the same ID):

```
Books
ID  Book ID  BookName
1   1        Fundamentals of calculus
2   2        Mechanics 
3   1        Fundamentals of calculus
4   3        Biology
```

In your first query, you do not specify what table the statement refers to (`FROM books`):

```
SELECT COUNT(bookId)
FROM books                                       <= Table Reference
WHERE BookName = "Fundamentals of calculus";
```

In the second query, you are using implicit syntax to join the tables. You should practice explicit joins like so:

```
SELECT Lib_Book_LookUp.libId, Libraries.Name
FROM Lib_Book_LookUp
INNER JOIN Libraries ON Libraries.ID = Lib_Book_LookUp.libId
WHERE bookId IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT bookId
    FROM books
    WHERE BookName = "Fundamentals of calculus")
```

This query joins the `Libraries` and `Lib_Book_LookUp` table, then finds the libraries that have the `bookId` of the book being searched.

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33eb5/1)

Answer (score -1):

Your books table looks more like an "Instances of a book" table. As such, it shouldn't have the bookname. Either that, or the `BookID` column is superfluous.

Your second query is correct, *if you are writing SQL from 1988*. If not, you should use the `join` syntax.